# Android custom button is smaller without reason

Tags: button, customization, font-size, android-styles

I have defined a custom button in Android.

This is my **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button</item>
</style>
```

And this is my **custom_button.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_disabled" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_disabled_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_custom_disabled" />
</selector>
```

Applying the custom background works, but all buttons are now smaller, and the captions of the buttons are smaller, too. Why? How can I make them appear exactly like the default buttons, but only with another background?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. I have to select a Holo button style as parent:

```
<style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button</item>
</style>
```